# andengine Google Plus Sign Button

Tags: java, android, google-plus, andengine

I am trying to impement Google Plus Sign Button on my android application that uses andengine and I am getting a NullPointException.
Here is my code

```
public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks,          OnConnectionFailedListener{

public static GameActivity gameActivity;
public static ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;

public static PlusClient mPlusClient;
public static ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
gameActivity = this;
}

public static void buttonPressed() {
    Log.e("pushNotification", "buttonPressed");
    if (!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {

        if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
            }

        try {

               mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(gameActivity,REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mConnectionResult = null;
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
    }
```

}

The static method buttonPressed is called on my Menu Scene. It works well untill it crashes on the line with the code:

```
mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(gameActivity, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
```

as I posted, it is called on the "try" part.

Does any one can help me? What I am doing wrong? What parameter do I have to pass instead of "gameActivity"???
Many Thanks

Comment: is it the gameActivity which is causing the NPE? (e.g. is that null?)

Comment: yes. Actually, I have implemented google plus in another game that doesn't use andengine and I just put "Activiy.this"as the parameter and it works. But I am not able to write gameActivity.this, I get an error saying that it cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 0):

run your buttonPressed() method on UI thread as follows:

```
 Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                buttonPressed();
            }
        });
```

Try this

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. Actually, the buttonPressed() is called on my MainMenu scene with the following code:          GameSceneManager.getInstance().getBaseGame().runOnUiThread(new       Runnable(){
    public void run() { gameActivity.buttonPressed(); } }): --> very similar to your code and it doesn't work!

Comment: Did you got any exception?If so, please provide log.